# How to make Container match parent in Sizebox

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 200,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 250,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const Text('456789', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15)),
                  SizedBox(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 10,
                      width: 100,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      // child: const Text('hello',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10)),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

I want to make black view match parent but I don't know how to make it match_parent

If I Set 'width: double.infinity', all views will disappear.

I have tried many solution in stackoverflow but not working

please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your `sizebox` using `expanded` and remove the width you got at the sizebox. and expanded will take all the leftover size in the column,

here is the edited code

```dart
 Container(
              width: 250,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const Text('456789',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15)),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 10,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      // child: const Text('hello',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10)),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
```

and this is the result I get

[image]

hope this help :)